# have a function redefine itself as it maps through a list

Tags: functional-style, memoization

I have a list which contains sublists, e.g.

```
list = {{a,b}, {a,b,c}, {a,b,a,a}, {b,c}, ...}
```

I then map a function through each sublist. This function should replace each occurrence of `a` by (say) a number, starting from 1 and increasing up to the total number of occurrences of `a`, like so:

```
Map[f,list,{2}]
(*{{1,b}, {1,b,c}, {1,b,2,3}, {b,c}, ...}*)
```

I remember I once saw a very clever implementation of something similar using memoization, but I could be mistaken. How can I write a suitable function `f` that would do do the job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without memoization but works too :)

```
Block[{i}, (i = 1; # /. a :> i++)] & /@ {{a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, a, a}, {b, c}}
```

---

And with:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a, _Integer] = 0;
f[a, {p_, _}] := f[a, p] += 1;
f[x_, _] := x;

MapIndexed[f,
 {{a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, a, a}, {b, c}},
 {2}
 ]
```

> ```
> {{1, b}, {1, b, c}, {1, b, 2, 3}, {b, c}}
> ```

Comment: Damn, 40 secs :)- Add a scoping construct for `i`, please:)

Comment: @Ziofil Please don't. It would be too soon :)

Comment: By the way, I used `Block` on the function instead of including the list: `Block[{i = 1}, # /. a :> i++] & /@list`, so that my function `f` is well defined

Comment: @Ziofil sure, that's seems more reasonable ;)

Comment: +1. Localizing `i` is quite difficult in this context.  `Block` is not sufficient -- try it with the list `{{a, a, i, a}}`.  The usual cure, `Module`, won't work here either due to inner scope renaming.  It will take some gymnastics to localize `i` properly: `Module[{i}, Module @@@ (Hold[{i = 1}, # /. a :> i++] &)]`. @belisarius

Comment: Another localization option is to avoid using a pure function, e.g. `Module[{f, i = 1}, f[x_] := x /. a :> i++; f] /@ {{a, a, i, a}}`.

Comment: @WReach Yup, that was the culprit of Kuba beating me to answer. At least I ended my comment with a smiley :D

Answer (score 6):

Here is a crude way using `FoldList`.

```
 foo[lis_, var_] := Module[{i, f}, f[var] := ++i;
    f[x_List] := f /@ x;
    f[x_] := x;
    Rest @ FoldList[(i = 0; f[#2]) &, var, lis]
  ]
```

Use:

```
foo[list, a]
```

> ```
> {{1, b}, {1, b, c}, {1, b, 2, 3}, {b, c}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the closurized way that the OP might have had in mind:

```
closfunc[l_]:= With[{foo = Module[{num}, num = 1; If[# == "a", num++, #] &]},
   Map[foo, l]]
```

Now `Map[closfunc, listoflists]` will do the right thing.